# Execute a sql query using another user account NT security

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, vbscript

I'm trying to configure a data feed from a SQL database (PeopleSoft), to a CSV file to be loaded into SAP PCM. I need this process to be run on an adhock basis and so needs to pull data rather than having it scheduled or pushed via an application such as SSIS or Control M.

Basically SAP PCM has the ability to allow custom coding (VBSCRIPT) which will allow us to shell out if required to run any type of third party script necessary to exucute the SQL QUERY which can be linked to a button in the application itself so the end user can just triger as required.

I've tried running the SQL directly from SAP PCM using a user account that has privileges to access the PeopleSoft database using SSO. As you would expect this works and the required data is output.

The problem is I don't want to give end users the same level of access ... so I have created a NT service account which has the correct level of database access. - We do not use SQL authentication here for some reason so can't just have a sql account.

The problem I'm facing is trying to get the SQL script to run as the service account... I've looked into RUN AS .. but this will prompt the user for the service account password - which defeats the point. Also the alternatives appear not to be supported after XP - we are using W7.

I've had a look at windows services which may hold the answer, but having never built one before I'd be starting totally from scratch and I'm not sure it is the best way forward.

The question therefore - is it possible to execute a SQL query, using a service account that does not prompt the user for a password? - I figure that I could build the password into an exe so that it is not stored clear text if required.

Does anyone have any example VBSCRIPT (Or other) that would allow me to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you maybe encode the pw so it is auto-entered when the user runs the process?

Comment: Hi, how would I get it to auto enter? - The only methods I've seen of doing that are using commands to send keys ... which doesn't seem very robust.

Comment: -EDIT- Too longwinded - posted as answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with the system you're using but I've just written a little batch file that uses bcp to copy a SQL stored procedure to a CSV. The file includes the username and PW.

It would look something like this:

```
bcp "exec [your SQL SP]" queryout output.csv -S[your server] -U[username] -P[PW] -c -t,
```

As you say not very secure (mine will be running as a scheduled task) but there's maybe another way to do something about that? Perhaps encrypt the batch file. There's a free program [here](http://www.battoexeconverter.com/) that appears to do that. From the blurb:

> Advanced BAT to EXE Converter not only encrypts your code, but you can
>   create an actual Windows native .EXE program.

Comment: Wouldn't that be the database username and password though? I can't see how that would authenticate using an NT account?